# Creating a mind-map application in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I apologise if the question is a little too broad. I would like to know how can I do something like the image below in Nuxt.js. It is like a mindmap where users can type things into the box. The boxes doesn't have to be able to move around. They can be just static in position. I'm only looking for solution to achieve this UI (no need for the logic and backend).

[image: Mind map application]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use and adapt [vue-mindmap](https://github.com/anteriovieira/vue-mindmap). It use d3 lib inside